# Finding the root of a multivariate function with scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I am looking for the root of a function for which I know that a root exists. The code below details two cases where the root is not found by scipy.optimize.root. My questions relate to what I can do to find the root (I already tried changing the starting point, the method, maxiter and xtol/ftol, but since I am new to python I may have not done it efficiently enough to make the program work).

First case: the root is found when the jacobian is not specified, but not when it is. What's wrong with the jacobian? 
Also, although the root is clearly not found, the algorithm returns success, why and how can I fix that?

Second case: the root is never found, how can I fix that?

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas 
import scipy
from scipy import optimize

# 1st case
# rap=np.array([.5,12.8,44,10.7,5,12.3])
# 2nd case
rap=np.array([1.2,83,5,41,7,50])

def f2(wc, a1, p0, a1pr, p0pr, atheta, x):
    A = (p0/(1-p0))**(1-a1)
    Apr = (p0pr/(1-p0pr))**(1-a1pr)
    return wc - (((A * x**a1)/(((1-x)**a1) + A * x**a1))*  (1-np.exp(-rap*atheta))/atheta) - (((Apr * (1-x)**a1pr)/((x**a1pr) + Apr * (1-x)**a1pr))*((1-np.exp(atheta))/atheta))

# define the derivative of f2 with respect to x (checked with sympy)
def f2p(wc, a1, p0, a1pr, p0pr, atheta, x):
    A = (p0/(1-p0))**(1-a1)
    Apr = (p0pr/(1-p0pr))**(1-a1pr)
    return - (((A*a1 * x**(a1-1) * (1-x)**(a1-1)) / (((1-x)**a1 + A * x**a1)**2))  \
        *(1-np.exp(-rap*atheta)/atheta)) \
         + (((Apr * a1pr * (1-x)**(a1pr-1) * x**(a1pr-1) ) / ((x**a1pr + Apr * (1-x)**a1pr)**2))  \
         *((1-np.exp(atheta))/atheta))

# f1 defines the function to find the root of
def f1(x, y):
    a1, p0, a1pr, p0pr, atheta = y[:5]
    tosolve = np.full_like(x, x[1:].sum()-1)
    tosolve[:-1] = f2(x[0], a1, p0, a1pr, p0pr, atheta, x[1:])
    return tosolve

# define the jacobian of f1 
def jac(x, y):
    a1, p0, a1pr, p0pr, atheta = y[:5]
    partial = f2p(x[0], a1, p0, a1pr, p0pr, atheta, x[1:])
    matrix = np.diag(partial)
    vector1 = np.full_like(rap,1)
    matrix1 = np.vstack((matrix, vector1))
    vector = np.full_like(x,1)
    vector[-1]=0
    matrix2 = np.column_stack((vector, matrix1))
    return matrix2

# f is finding the roots of f1
def f(y):
    a1, p0, a1pr, p0pr, atheta = y[:5] 
    x0 = [0.000001,0.000001,0.000001,0.000001,0.000001,0.000001,0.000001] 
    print 'x0', x0
    sol = scipy.optimize.root(f1, x0, args=(y), method='lm')
#    sol = scipy.optimize.root(f1, x0, args=(y), method='lm', jac=jac,options={'maxiter': 5000})
    return sol

# 1st case   
# result = f([.8,0.03,0.8,0.3,-0.01])
# 2nd case
result = f([1.99,0.01,1.99,0.989,-0.43])
print result
```

Comment: what is the `root of a vector`?

Comment: @cel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_of_a_function

Comment: 1) You can also use `scipy.optimize.check_grad` to check that your jacobian is correct. 2) Well you are numerically solving a system of non linear equations which is a difficult problem. You can a) play with the convergence threshold, number of iterations etc b) do more systematic variations in the initial conditions to see if you get a significant difference in the result. Also note that knowing that a root exist, doesn't say whether it is unique...

Comment: @rth Thank you for the advice. 1) there was a mistake in the gradient 2) Is it possible that in some specific cases scipy.optimize.root will not find the root?  I have a particular case where whatever I seem to do it won't find it. Sorry I did not say it but solution exists and is unique.